# How to get public URL of Facebook Marketplace Catalog product

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm developing an application that auto upload listing to a FB Marketplace Catalog using [Catalog Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch)

All good except one thing: I can see my listing in the Catalog Manager, but I can not get it's URL to share. The app is still in development mode and I want to get listings' URL to check if the app is working fine.

How can I get the public URL of a catalog listing? Do I need to purchase ads for it or not?